# Json_encode not print anything

Tags: php, json

I'm building a PHP page, that return a list of items from my database. So I can't see any record because I think that the script go in overflow.

This is my script

```
    <?php 
    ini_set('memory-limit','-1');
    set_time_limit(0);
    require_once('lib/connection.php'); 
        $query_Articolo = "SELECT CodArticolo,NomeArticolo,Quantita,CodiceBarre, PrezzoAttuale, PrezzoRivenditore,PrezzoIngrosso 
         FROM VistaArticoli";
        $result_Articoli = $connectiondb->query($query_Articolo);
//I HAVE JUST INSERT THIS LINE CODE        
$answer[] =array();            
        while($row_Articoli = $result_Articoli->fetch_assoc()) {
            $answer[] =array("id"=>$row_Articoli['CodArticolo'],"nome"=>$row_Articoli['NomeArticolo'],
                "quantita"=>$row_Articoli['Quantita'],"codiceBarre"=>$row_Articoli['CodiceBarre']
                ,"codartFornitore"=>$row_Articoli['CodiceBarre'], "PrezzoAttuale"=>$row_Articoli['PrezzoAttuale'],
                "prezzoRivenditore"=>$row_Articoli['prezzoRivenditore'],"prezzoIngrosso"=>$row_Articoli['prezzoIngrosso']);
        }
        //echo "risposta";
        echo json_encode($answer);
    ?>
```

If I try tu call this page, I can't see any record. If I add at the query "limit 500" I can see the result.
How can I change the code?

Comment: $answer variable is not defined before usage. Pleas try to add $answer = array() before while loop.

Comment: How many rows are in this table?

Comment: I have insert $answer variable, but not works.
@raphael75 this table have 2000 record or more

Comment: Have you checked to see if any errors are returned from the database?

Comment: No there isn't any error. If I try to add at my query limit 500, I can see the response